# Publish the server project from Visual Studio to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, xamarin

I'm trying to publish the sample project for mobile backend as explain here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#install-sdk

unfortunately I can't follow the correct procedure because I haven't "Microsoft Azure App Service" button.

Here it is what I have:

[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you do not have the last version of the Azure Tools for Visual Studio. You can download the latest version from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/azure-tools-vs.aspx

The last version is 2.9 published on March, 30th.

After installing this version you should have the Azure App Service option available, as displayed on the first capture on the page linked above.